# SCons setup for hierarchical source but single target

Tags: c++, python, build, scons

I have a C++/Python project that I've been working on and so far have relied on Visual Studio to manage the builds.  Now I want to automate the build process, hopefully include multiple platform support (it's all standard C++/Python), and think SCons could be the tool to do the job.

There's a lot of source files involved, in multiple directories, but a (stereo)typical example is as follows:

```
foo.lib
  directory_1
    bar1_1.cpp
    bar1_2.cpp
    ... etc. ...
  directory_2
    bar2_1.cpp
    bar2_2.cpp
    ... etc. ...
```

So, in other words, the source files are in a hierarchy, but there's only a single target.  (The hierarchy is matched in the namespaces used in the code, but this is superfluous for purposes of this question.)

My question is: What's the best way to structure the SConstruct and SConscript files?  I read the SCons documentation, particularly, the Hierarchical Builds section and the idea to use multiple SConscript files with suitable 'SConscript' calls.  All seems clear, and particularly neat.  However it would seem this is intended for a hierarchy with multiple targets.  Can I use this same feature where there's only one target?

(I did think of a top level SConstruct/SConscript file, at least for the library in question, listing all the source file with subdirectories, but doesn't "feel" the best way to do it.  Maybe indeed this is the way forward?)

Many thanks in advance for any advice / insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with listing all the source files in one `SConstruct` file. Hierarchically structuring SConscripts is also fine, but you will need to return objects from each layer, which will get a little silly:

```
# SConscript, for example
sources = ["bar1_1.cpp", "bar1_2.cpp", ...]
objects = [env.Object(x) for x in sources]
Return(objects)

# SConstruct (top-level)
directory_1_objects = SConscript("directory_1/SConscript")
directory_2_objects = SConscript("directory_2/SConscript")
program = env.Program("magical_wonders", [directory_1_objects, directory_2_objects])
```

In my own opinion, a single top-level raster of all the source files in a particular binary is preferable to this, which requires more wiring when the file hierarchy changes.

Comment: Thanks!  This certainly highlights a feature I obviously skipped (or misunderstood) in the documentation.

My request stemmed from two cases I wanted to handle:
i) selective inclusion of certain files; and
ii) specifying different build flags for individual files.

Upon review, case (i) is really an instance of me being lazy.  Now I'm just stuck with case (ii) - an example would be disabling a warning for a specific file, but not disabling it globally.  (I was hoping to handle this via suitable environment handling in the particular SConscript file.  Though again I may be off in the weeds...)

Answer (score 5):

I have several times used a hierarchical solution much like the one you describe. I have chosen a solution like this:

in the SConscript:

```
#/bar/SConscript
Import("env")
env = specialize_env_for_this_subpackage()

myfiles = Glob(*.cpp)
apply_any_exclusions(myfiles)
myobjects = env.Object(myfiles)

Return(myobjects)
```

then in the SConstruct:

```
#SConstruct
env = construct_general_environment()

subpackages = ["foo","bar","baz"] #or perhaps call your own find_subproject() function

objects = SCons.Node.NodeList
for package in subpackages:
    pack_objects = env.SConscript(os.path.join(package,"SConscript"), exports = env)
    objects.extend(pack_objects)
program = env.Program("myprog",objects)

Default(program)
```

Then you have fine tuned control over the environment in each package, and with clever use of the *site_scons* folder you can prevent repeating the same lines over and over for each sconscript. Another advantage with this approach is that the scons files reflects the design. I also prefer using a *Glob* to gather cpp files, allowing me to add and remove files as I like, without editing any build files for such trivial operations.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to try it out tonight, and I think it's almost exactly what I was looking for.  The only outstanding item is to change the build flags for particular files (to disable warnings generated by including 3rd party libraries, etc.).  I can live with the warnings though...

Comment: remember to make a deep-copy of the environment when you change it, or else the change will affect later packages. env.Clone() will make a good copy of the environment.

Comment: Yes - a good point!  Of course I ran into this one immediately :-) .  Your comment confirmed where I was going wrong.